# how to secure my javascript client in which users will fill their passwords

Tags: javascript, passwords, security

How I have a basic javascript registration form which sends the password that an user has filled to a secure axis2  web service (which stores the salted hash of the password in a database).

Mu question is - is there ANY WAY the password to be cracked before it's send to the server as the user enters plain text password and it's hashed on the server side.

How can I secure my javascript client and can you recommend some libraries.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How can plaintext be "cracked"?

Answer (score 5):

The passwords are sent in plaintext, and can be easily sniffed/spoofed via man in the middle attacks like [ARP posioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) (in which someone on the same subnetwork as you or your client can sniff and manipulate packets).

Get an [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) certificate and enable [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) for your website (instructions for apache [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/349)).

For some more details on why there's no point securing stuff on the client side, see my answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34961/web-insecure-http-using-rsa-for-encrypting-passwords-on-the-client-side/34963#34963). Basically, unless there is a certificate-based trust system like in HTTPS, an attacker can always spoof whatever encryption protocol you try by modifying keys on the fly or removing the encryption code from the javascript.

Comment: How can the hacker modifying keys on the fly or removing the encryption code from the javascript? You mean sniffing the javascript response from server to client?

Comment: @KhanhTo: Yes. If one is able to sniff packets, one is also able to modify them. (See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34965/)

Answer (score 1):

Unless the connection is in HTTPS, the password *is* sent in plaintext. There is no client-side code that can help you with that.

Comment: Not true technically, if for example the server would send a publc key and the client would encode the password with the public key the password is not sent in plaintext anymore. The true problem lies in the fact that a man in the middle could easily alter the code in such a way that the password is sent in plaintext by the browser, so using SSL is of course the right way to go (and encrypting the password client side is pointless without SSL), but it *is* possible. Doing the hasing on client side is possible as well (but pointless).

Comment: @DavidMulder: Yep. I explained as much [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34961/web-insecure-http-using-rsa-for-encrypting-passwords-on-the-client-side/34963#34963) -- unless you use a certificate-based system like HTTPS, any MITM attack can always modify the keys on the fly.

Comment: @DavidMulder Like I said, no client side code can help. Possible yet pointless.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer You actually said the password is always sent in plaintext which is not the same as 'possible yet pointless'. But whatever, we agree with eachother.

Comment: @Manishearth Btw, storing the public key on the client would help a bit (similar to ssh fingerprinting where you accept the fingerprint only if you know to be on a secure connection), but of course a MITM could alter the code sent to the client which (once again) makes it pointless :P **But** that doesn't mean everything is pointless. In theory it would be possible to write an implementation of for example a Diffie–Hellman key exchange in javascript which wouldn't be pointless, but that's honestly beyond me O:)

Comment: @DavidMulder: Well, you'd need a secure way of getting the key to the client (relying on some other https service to do this maybe?). Diffie-Hellman exchanges only work if the unencrypted stream is read only. I can position myself in between, pretend to be Alice whilst communicating with Bob and vice versa.

Comment: @Manishearth For that you would have to get to STS right...? Honestly, I just use https and don't really care about the underlying systems. All I do know is that there has to be (by definition) a way where the password could be securely send *provided* that the initial connection (similar to pre shared certificates) establishment was secure all consequent connections should be able to establish a secure channel (though you would need HTML5 offline storage to prevent the MITM to tamper with the relevant code)

Comment: @Manishearth Station-to-Station protocol

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **protect the data transmission between the client and the server from eavesdroppers**, there's a standard solution for it: [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer).